# Should I use partitions in this case

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, partitioning, database-performance

I have the following table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `connections` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `to_from` (`user_id_to`,`user_id_from`),
 KEY `user_id_from` (`user_id_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1559108041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

It is 103GB (43GB Data and 59GB Index) and about ~1,143,663,061 rows. I assume the main performance barrier is a result of the size of the index, and therefore the solution will probably mean reduce it into small indexes (partition). I'm considering adding a DATE field and doing a partition by MONTH. I can live with each time querying only the recent X months (X will be around 6). The Con I see is this will cause the table to become bigger than it is right now.

Before I benchmark, would you recommend that? Do you have other suggestions?

UPDATE: 
The queries I'm using on this table:
`SELECT * FROM connections WHERE user_id_to=x LIMIT 3000`
`SELECT * FROM connections WHERE user_id_from=x ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 100`
`SELECT user_id_from, counter FROM connections WHERE user_id_to IN (x1, x2, ..., x1000) LIMIT 500`
`SELECT * FROM connections WHERE user_id_to=x AND user_id_from IN (x1, x2, ..., x1000) LIMIT 1000`

The reason I query by user_id_to as the main condition and also by user_id_from as the main condition, is there connections are directional, and I'm looking for mutual connections (to->from && from->to). The amount of rows for `WHERE user_id_to` can be very high, be `WHERE user_id_from` is mostly not so much, that's why when I `ORDER BY counter` I didn't add an index for that.

Comment: See answer below about possibly removing one of your indexes. Also, it's strange that you would have `_from` and `_to` and INT fields instead of date fields. And keeping them unique in the entire table means no two users can have the same start and end dates, which is also strange.

Comment: _"Before I benchmark..."_ - You should benchmark **first** and identify the exact queries being slow (and their timings and execution plans). Is there a [specific reason](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) for the surrogate key `id`? If not, you can just omit it, and use `{user_id_to, user_id_from}` as the primary key, cutting the required storage. In addition to that, I suspect a composite index on `{user_id_from, user_id_to}` might serve you better than `{user_id_from}` alone. But all these are conjectures without knowing your queries.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Interesting idea to remove the surrogate key. It doesn't have any specific reason, but I've found these useful in some cases (for example when wanting to iterate a table in chunks). Wouldn't a `{user_id_from, user_id_to}` index be much bigger than `{user_id_from}`?  Why do you suspect it will serve me better? Any thought regarding the partition option?

Comment: @Noam `{user_id_from, user_id_to}` might be able to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the typical queries better than `{user_id_from}` alone - of course that's impossible to actually know without knowing the exact query, and you'd have to balance against possible increase in size (see below).

Comment: @Noam As for the size, this index will be somewhat larger if you keep using `{id}` as PK, or essentially the same if `{user_id_to, user_id_from}` is the PK, because [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), and therefore secondary indexes **implicitly contain all PK fields**, so `{user_id_to}` would implicitly contain `user_id_from` anyway. I think it's a little too early to think about partitioning before identifying the actual performance bottleneck.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I didn't not know that about InnoDB. Just to verify I understood: if I use  your suggested PK, an index on `{user_id_from}` will be the same as a composite index `{user_id_from, user_id_to}`? I've also updated the question with details on the queries I'm running on the table, does that help?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic also, in order to be in control of table size and be able to delete old rows easily, would you recommend adding partitioning just for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove one index `user_id_from` by modifying the unique key (depending on how your queries use them): Instead of `to_from`, make it **`from_to`** as `(user_id_from,user_id_to)`, like **start-end**. Then you wouldn't need the 2nd index on `user_id_from` since the first part of the composite index/key `user_id_from` would be used even when the second part is not required (`user_id_to`).

So you'd only need:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
UNIQUE KEY `from_to` (`user_id_from`,`user_id_to`)
```

That's one change to save space used by indexes. (Test it with a small subset of your table and see the `EXPLAIN` result). PS: When you go ahead with this change, drop the `user_id_*` indexes and then create the `from_to` index in case you're within 30 GB of your disk limit.

Specifically to your question...
If old data won't be required, it may make more sense to either:

1. delete old rows, like when `user_id_to` is more than 1 yr ago; or,
2. (with option 1) - create a table like `old_users` and just add their IDs and `user_id_to` fields if you require that info.
3. insert old rows of `connections` in a new table like `connections_archive` and then delete from `connections`. Assuming you would either never query `_archive` in your app's queries or only from an admin interface (i.e. rarely) in which case, a performance hit on a 'union' query with `connections` and `connections_archive` would be bearable.

Comment: I've updated the question with the queries I'm running on this table, please correct me if I'm wrong but I assume your solution doesn't cover a query like `WHERE user_id_to=x` which I need.

Comment: You're correct, I assumed you wouldn't have a query which only uses `user_id_to` without `user_id_from`. Hence I suggested the composite `{user_id_from, user_id_to}` instead of to-from. Some of Branko's comments might address your issue better.